# Laravel 5.3 : Sending back array after validation gives error

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

I have my view as

```
<input type="text" name="color[]" value="{{ old('color') }}" placeholder="Enter Color">
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="{{ old('price') }}" placeholder="Enter Price">
```

And since price and color are an array, trying to send back the value that is array after validation is giving error.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);  

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('rate/create')
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
```

Here **withInput()** is giving error.And error is as follow:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /Users/.../www/abc/resources/views/abc/create.blade.php).
```

How can I send that errors to view after validation. Also I need to validate this arrays too. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<input type="text" name="color[]" value="{{Input::old('color') }}" placeholder="Enter Color">
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="{{Input::old('price') }}" placeholder="Enter Price">
```

I have made changes from `old` to `Input::old`.

Here is sample documentation link for [server side validation](https://ahesanalisuthar.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/laravel-form-validation-a-server-side-concern/)

I hope this will work.

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I want. I want that color and price array to be passed to my view when validation fails. @Swapper

Comment: dd once in method you load that view and check if you are getting